# Разделить массив байт java

Tags: java

Если размер массива больше 128 необходимо его разделить на массивы по 128 байт.

```
 private List<byte[]> getBytesList(String str) {
        byte[] bytes = str.getBytes();

        List<byte[]> bytesList = new ArrayList<>();

        if (bytes.length < 128) {
            bytesList.add(bytes);
        } else {

        }

        return bytesList;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очень интересное задание, предлагаю вот такой вариант.

**Update**

Предыдущий вариант работал с англ. символами по 1 byte, новая версия кода работает с любыми. Соответственно если надо разложить **Object** можно изменить принимаемый параметр на **Object** в методе **getList**, получить байты в **str_b** из **Object** и отправить в путешествие по методу.

```
    package demo;

    import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String str = "Arguments: Привет [-PcmdLineArgs=, Привет -PjvmLineArgs=, Привет -c, /home/ufo/NetBeansПриветProjects/Demo/settings.gradle]";
            System.out.println("str  byte len = "  + str.getBytes().length);


            for(byte[] item : getList(str, 12)){
                // Debug
                System.out.println("item len = "  + item.length);
                System.out.println(new String(item, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            }
        }
    // Метод getList(String, int) принимает на вход 2 параметра:
    // 1. Строка
    // 2. Размер массива
        static List<byte[]> getList(String str, int len) {
            List<byte[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
            byte[] str_b = str.getBytes();
            int count = (int)Math.ceil((double)str_b.length / len);
            System.out.println("count = "  + count);
            int start_position = 0;
            int end_position = len;
            for(int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
                //Примечание: end_position - Этот индекс может находиться вне массива.
                list.add(Arrays.copyOfRange(str_b, start_position, end_position));

                start_position += len;
                end_position = start_position + len;

            }
            return list;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо за решение.

Comment: Интересно, почему 12? И да, количество символов не соответствует количеству байтов.

Comment: @hmeli7 Если этот ответ решает Вашу проблему, то [отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: 12 мы задаем размер массива

Comment: Может еще подскажите как быть если на вход мы принимаем Object
Как я понимаю его надо преобразовать в массив байт:

     ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutput out = null;
        byte[] bytes = null;
        try {
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
            out.writeObject(object);
            out.flush();
            bytes = bos.toByteArray();
        } finally {
            baos.close();
        }

Answer (score 0):

Создавайте новый массив на 128 элементов и копируйте их. Ведите счетчик сколько байтов считали и если "общие байты"-"сохраненные байты" больше 128 то повторяете.